# Angular 15.1 unit test failed when class has static data

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-webpack

I have an Angular 15.0 project that worked well until I upgraded it to Angular 15.1.

For example this code failed when running unit tests:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'mad-zoom-control',
  templateUrl: './zoom-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./zoom-control.component.scss']
})
export class ZoomControlComponent extends MadComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() conserveRatio          = true;
  @Input() dropupPredefinedOption = true;
  @Input() showPredefined         = true;
  @Input() showZoomFactor         = true;
  @Input() zone: Zone             = null;

  @Output() readonly zoomChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  // Predefined Zoom -> Predefined Zoom Label
  static PredefinedZoomEnumMapList = [
    ['full',        MAD_FULL],
    ['center',      MAD_MenuPositionEnum_eCENTER],
    ['left',        MAD_ZoneJustifyXEnum_eLEFT],
    ['right',       MAD_ZoneJustifyXEnum_eRIGHT],
    ['top',         MAD_ZoneJustifyXEnum_eTOP],
    ['bottom',      MAD_ZoneJustifyXEnum_eBOTTOM],
    ['topLeft',     MAD_MenuPositionEnum_eTOP_LEFT],
    ['topRight',    MAD_MenuPositionEnum_eTOP_RIGHT],
    ['bottomLeft',  MAD_MenuPositionEnum_eBOTTOM_LEFT],
    ['bottomRight', MAD_MenuPositionEnum_eBOTTOM_RIGHT],
  ];

  static PredefinedZoomEnumLabelList = ZoomControlComponent.PredefinedZoomEnumMapList.map((zoneAspect) => zoneAspect[1]);
```

The issue is:

```
Chrome 109.0.0.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PredefinedZoomEnumMapList')
  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PredefinedZoomEnumMapList')
      at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/widgets/zoom-control/zoom-control.component.ts:60:61
      at Module.13225 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/widgets/zoom-control/zoom-control.component.ts:60:122)
...
```

I don't see any open issue in Angular or Angular CLI Github repos.

Any help is welcome.

I ran `yarn test-coverage` and just want no error as usual.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/48764) waiting to be fixed. Investigations report that this happens since `15.1.0-rc.0`